# deleting field from document that meet some criteria

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

How to delete a fields from documents that meet some criteria?
For exmaple, I inserted in mongodb command line documents:

```
db.test1.insert({LISTID: 52, 259: 180})
db.test1.insert({LISTID: 52, 259: 185})
```

Then I try to delete fields "259" for all documents with LISTID: 52:

```
db.test1.update({LISTID: 52}, {$unset: {"259" : 1}})
```

I looks like it delete fields "259" only for first document, but doesn't delete for the last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the multiple flag to true :

```
db.test1.update({LISTID: 52}, {$unset: {"259" : 1}}, false, true)
```

By default MongoDB only updates the first document that matches the criteria.

Comment: Thank, it looks like it works in mongo command line. And it seems it works in php too.